# Mongodb - 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport-local

I'm trying to use Advanced Rest Client to see if my MongoDB has been set up correctly, but it keeps giving me a 500: Internal Server Error.

This is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/emedb');
var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var authenticate = require('./routes/authenticate')(passport);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(session({
    secret: '<never-tell>',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
// Initialize models
require('./models/models.js')
// Initialize Passport
var initPassport = require('./passport-init');
initPassport(passport);
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/auth', authenticate);
```

I have a 'passport-init.js' file in the root directory of the app with this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Users = mongoose.model('Users');
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');


module.exports = function(passport){

// Passport needs to be able to serialize and deserialize users to support persistent login sessions
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    // tell passport which id to use for user
    console.log('serializing user:', user._id);
    return done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    //returns user object back
    Users.findById(id, function(err, user){
        if (err){
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if(!user){
            return done('Username not found', false);
        }
        // user object found - provided back to passport
        return done(user, true);
    });
});

passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, username, password, done) { 


        Users.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user){
            if(err){
                return done(err, false);
            }

            // no user with username
            if (!user){
                return done('uesr ' + username + ' not found', false);
            }

            // incorrect password
            if(!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                return done('incorrect password', false);
            }

            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));

passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },

    function(req, username, password, done) {

        // find a user in mongo with provided username
        Users.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, function(err, user) {
            // In case of any error, return using the done method
            if (err){
                return done(err);
            }
            if(user){
                // user already signed up
                return done('username taken', false);
            }
            else{
            // no user exists - create new user
            var user = new Users();
            user.username = username;
            user.password = createHash(password);

                user.save(function(err, user){
                    if(err){
                        return done(err, false);
                    }
                console.log('Thank You For Signing Up');
                return done(null, user);
            });
            }
        });
    })
);  


/*              });
            };
        });
    };
*/



var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
    return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
};
// Generates hash using bCrypt
var createHash = function(password){
    return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
};


};
```

And, I have a folder called models with a 'models.js' file that has this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String //hash created from password

});

mongoose.model("Users", userSchema);
```

Please excuse the large volume of code, I'm a bit of a noob and really don't know where I've gone wrong.

Comment: I can't find a stack trace, but when I use the shell to check the contents of the db, I get all the records I added to the db using Advanced Rest Client.

Comment: If you are getting 500 error, then at app level, you must be getting error trace ?

Comment: Don't know how to get that working either, that could be a whole other question

Comment: you're running the server from the command line right? when this 500 error occurs you can see the error trace in the command line/terminal. paste it in the question pls

Comment: There's no error in the command. It just has the '500' and the time it takes to process. All the data I've been posting from Advanced Rest Client is in the database, so I'm wondering if the problem is with the Chrome app.

Comment: Just checked again and I found data in my DB, in array form `db.users.find().toArray()` I got this info from a video tutorial and after watching the end of the video they had problems with Advanced Rest Client as well. So, that might be it. I'll post again if find out anything more.